# Is this patent expired?

Tags: expired-patent

Is the 
[USD388287 S](http://www.google.com/patents/USD388287)
patent expired? I am looking to design something similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

Design patents filed before Dec 18, 2013 have a patent term of 14 years from the date of grant. See http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2701.html#sect2701.

The design patent you listed was granted on Dec 30, 1997 and so it expired Dec 30, 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Patents are typically granted for 20 years, which for this patents still have a few years to go.

The patent is a design patent, and it looks to me that the what is patented is the exact liking -- so you may be Ok to design something similar as long as it is not exactly the same.